# is OAuth 2.0 stateful?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am new to OAuth, something that I do not understand is how `Resource Server` use `access_token` to know if the user has enough permissions for the requested resource or not.

I have three specific questions:

**first**: does `Resource Server` call `authorization Server` for every `access_token` (for example to get user information such as username,..)?

**second**: does `authorization Server` store any data about issued `access_token`s? and if yes, can I make it stateless?

**third**: I want to develop an application with microservice architecture, an authentication/authorization server(with OAuth) and other services, and I want all my services to be completely stateless (I mean my services should not call OAuth server at all, and get all necessary information from the access_token such as username, etc..), is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 protocol leaves state up to the implementation. From the [specification doc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4):

> The token may denote an identifier used to retrieve the authorization
> information or may self-contain the authorization information in a
> verifiable manner (i.e., a token string consisting of some data and a
> signature).  Additional authentication credentials, which are beyond
> the scope of this specification, may be required in order for the
> client to use a token.

So its up to you how you want it implemented. For stateless implementation look at [JWT tokens](https://jwt.io/) which are encrypted tokens which can contain all information your resource server needs to know. I'd look at [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) protocol that should suite your needs.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth will perform entry point authorization, but typically you'll also want to do deeper authorization within each API. My write up may help you understand how to grow your micro-services in this area. The design involves some easy to manage state, and caching of claims is a [common pattern](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/).